# Define route without ending slash when importing route in Symfony 2.5?

Tags: symfony, url-routing, yaml, routes

In file: HardCoreMore/HRAPIBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

I have imported route like this:

```
hr_api_company:
resource: "@HRAPIBundle/Resources/config/routing/company.yml"
prefix: /company
```

And in file: HardCoreMore/HRAPIBundle/Resources/config/routing/company.yml

I have defined route for creating company like this:

```
hardcoremore_hr_api_company_create:
pattern: /
defaults: { _controller: HRAPIBundle:Company:create }
methods:  [POST]
```

Now the route is matched with following url:

POST company/

but it is not matched when I called it with:

POST company

How can I define route without ending slash when importing route and prefixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not possible, see : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4322

I hope this has helped

Comment: Ok thanks. I hope they will address this in the future.

Comment: Superseding ticket for this issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12141